# How to retrieve the last inserted value in a column using CoreData?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

In my CoreData application I want display the last inserted `stdId` in `Table` Student. Is there any easy way to retrieve the last inserted value in a column ?

Comment: sorry for my question but... are you sure how the `CoreData` really works?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple if in your `Student` entity you add a property of type `NSDate` like `createdAt`.

When you insert a new `Student`, you need to pass the current date for that property.

```
[aStudent setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"createdAt"];
```

or

```
aStudent.createdAt = [NSDate date];
```

if you have created a subclass of `Entity`.

Once done, you can fetch against `Student` using a limit of 1 and a sort descriptor with ascending value `NO`.

```
NSFetchRequest* request = [NSFecthRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Student"];
[request setFetchLimit:1];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"createdAt" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSError *error;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

NSManagedObject *latestAddedStudent = [results objectAtIndex:0];
```

Hope that helps.