# CoreData sort by creation order

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

Wondering, if possible, how I would go about sorting entities from an NSSet by the order in which they were created.

I'm able to sort them by certain attributes, but can't work out how to sort by creation order.

Thanks

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363910/how-to-retrieve-the-last-inserted-value-in-a-column-using-coredata/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do this with Core Data is to provide a `creationDate` field in the `Entity` and fill this. You could fill this within the entity itself in `-willSave` for example, so that the controller that deal with your model does not have to mess with that.